# Open shell of container when write start command

Tags: command-line, powershell, docker, container, .net-core

When i want to open shell of container when `start` container i get this error

I use this command :

```
docker start -i <Container name> sh
```

but get this error :

> you cannot start and attach multiple containers at once

Problem create when docker app is a console application and when i start container in Ubuntu console is run and can't write any command

How can i fix this problem?

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found. For console app doesn't run in command line we must remove `-i` to container **doesn't** run as **interactive :**

```
docker start <Container name>
```

next `execute` as manual way :

```
docker exec -it <Container name> sh
```